# BigQuery data dump into CloudSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I want that for first request data come from Bigquery and dumped into cloudSQL and for second request from the same user for the same query.Data will be displayed from cloud SQL.How i can make this possible in a web application hosted on GAE.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to run a query using the BigQuery API, have the resulting table data put into Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this type of problem is.Create Cron job on GAE.this cron job will pull data from big query and insert it into CloudSQL.Always show the data to user by Querying CloudSQL.

It is advised to assign some Version ID to records when a cron job run.It is required because if we run the cron job next day then there will be possibility of duplicate records.So when next day/next time cron job run,It will truncate data with a particular version id and then insert the data in clodSQL with new version id.